# How to place a java class in xml

Tags: android, android-layout

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
CoverFlow coverFlow = new CoverFlow(this);
setContentView(coverFlow);
}
```

This is my code, but now I want to place a layout in that same file.
Any suggestions please.......

Comment: i dont think that you can use setContentView twice

Comment: The example of how to use coverflow within a layout is here
http://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/source/browse/res/layout/main.xml what's wrong with that layout that you can't use?

Comment: @Waqas - There's nothing wrong with calling `setContentView` twice. (It's fairly useless to do it twice in `onCreate`, but that's another matter.)

Comment: ahaaan, thanks i didnt know that. I thought some sort of exception is thrown if we call it twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom view in an XML file by simply using its fully qualified name as the root element tag. If `CoverFlow` was in package `com.example`, you would code it something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.CoverFlow
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Then, if the above were in the file `res/layout/main.xml`, you would use it by calling:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you are talking about to include that [**`Custom Components`**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) that you have defined as CoverFlow, if you are talking about to include this CoverFlow components in your xml layout then here is a basic example:

```
<view
  class="com.example.CoverFlow" 
  id="@+id/CoverFlow"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@android:drawable/empty"
  android:padding="10dip"
  android:scrollbars="vertical"
  android:fadingEdge="vertical" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use RelativeLayout as a parent View
Use RelativeLayout.addView(coverFlow, new LayoutParams(fillParent,fillParent));
setContentView(RelativeLayout);

and if you want to display another one.
you can RelativeLayout.removeView(coverFlow);
and Add the target one to RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

show one view every time by call: viewSwitcher.showNext();

```
<ViewSwitcher android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <com.example.CoverFlow
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        <include layout="@layout/your_layout_here" android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </ViewSwitcher>
```

show by overlaping:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/container"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                            <com.example.CoverFlow
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

       <!-- the other View/Layout here->

</FrameLayout>
```